# JShint acts differently on different machines despite same code, versions and config

Tags: javascript, node.js, jenkins, jshint, grunt-contrib-jshint

I have the following `JShint` related modules versions on my `local machine` and our `jenkins build` machine, which runs jshint before building the `UI`:

```
npm -v                                // 2.14.7
npm view jshint version               // 2.9.2
npm view grunt version                // 1.0.1
npm view grunt-contrib version        // 0.11.0
npm view grunt-contrib-jshint version // 1.0.0
```

Both machines use the same `.jshintrc` config file.

When i run jshint on locally i get `no problems`.
When i run it on the `build machine` (same code of course) - i get many errors.

I'm pretty sure it's versions related since the config and code are the same but i don't know where else to look.

Thanks!

Comment: Double check `jshinrc` option in `grunt-contrib-jshint` task configuration.

Comment: It's the same configuration (same files)

Comment: `jshintrc` option, If set to true, no config will be sent to JSHint and JSHint will search for .jshintrc files relative to the files being linted.

Comment: `jshintrc` option is set to the location of the `.jshintrc` file, which is the same on both machines. I've confirmed it uses the right config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, i was using the wrong command to check my installed packages versions:

```
npm view <package_name> version; // returns the latest available version of the package.
```

The command i needed to use was:

```
npm list <package_name>; // returns the installed package (and it's dependencies) version
```

After using the right command i saw that

**local**: `npm list grunt-contrib-jshint; // 0.11.0 depends on JShint ~2.6.0`
**jenkins**: `npm list grunt-contrib-jshint; // 1.0.0 depends on JShint ~2.9.1`

And was getting errors on `jenkins machine` since `JShint ~2.9.1` is much stricter than `JShint ~2.6.0`.